# How do I download failed pipeline runs in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

[Screenshot of failed runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09esW.png)

I want to download all the failed pipeline runs in a csv or excel format. Is that possible in Azure data factory?

Comment: Have you checked out the [pipeline runs get API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get#pipelinerun) ?

Comment: How do I invoke this?

Comment: It is actually a RESTful endpoint provided by Microsoft. You can either trigger it by postman / cURL. For a quick tryout, you can simply try the **Try It** button in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below link and the code snippets to query failed pipelines and you can write to a csv file in python or .net in  Azure functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically